# Expectation of conditional variance in a GARCH(1,1) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, mathematical-statistics, garch

Given the GARCH(1,1) model

\begin{aligned}
X_{t} &= \sigma_{t}Z_{t} \\
\sigma^{2}_{t} &= \alpha_{0} + \alpha_{1}X^{2}_{t-1} + \beta_{1}\sigma^{2}_{t-1}
\end{aligned}

where the process $Z_{t} \sim^{\text{iid}} N(0,1)$ and also

\begin{aligned}
\alpha_{0} &> 0 \\ 
\alpha_{1} &\geq 0 \\
\beta_{1} &\geq 0 \\
\alpha_{1} + \beta_{1} &< 1,
\end{aligned}

how does one show that

$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}_{t} | X^{2}_{t-1}, X^{2}_{t-2}, X^{2}_{t-3},\dots] = \sigma^{2}_{t}?$$

Comment: This might need the self study tag.

Comment: One of the key properties of GARCH (and why it is much easier to fit than the related "stochastic volatility" models) is that the volatility process $\sigma_t^2$ is not stochastic conditional on the information up to $t-1$ (i.e. it is known exactly, 1 period in advance). This result is a direct consequence of that.

Comment: Hints: (1) Variance equality: $\mathbb{V}ar(Y) + \mathbb{E}(Y)^2 = \mathbb{E}(Y^2)$, and the second,   (2) Conditioning on the 'filtration' $X_{t-1}, \dots, X_{1}, X_{0}$, means that all those values are considered known for the sake of calculating expectations, i.e. treat them as constants.